# Gradle build fails every time

Tags: android, gradle

I updated my Android tools today and the now the gradle always fails to finish its job. It says

> Error:A problem was found with the configuration of task
>   :app:zipalignDebug. File
>   D:\Projects\AppName\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug-unaligned.apk
>   specified for property inputFile does not exist.

Actually there isn't even any file called app-debug-unaligned.apk in my apk folder.

Comment: did you try and clean / rebuild the whole project?

Comment: Yes, I've already tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

1. Delete `build` folders
2. File -> Invalidate Caches & Restart
3. Build -> Clean Project
4. Build -> Rebuild Project
5. Run `assembleRelease` task (either from the command line or from the Gradle tasks view)
6. Run `build` task

Comment: It didn't work. The same error message. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Correct solution. Now it launches the program.

Comment: Awesome. Happy coding.. :)